# Javascript - Merge two dimensional array with unique result

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have this two array in Javascript

```
var array1 = [
              ["Tech & Digital", 124],
              ["Stationery", 100]
             ]
var array2 = [
              ["Gift Item", 125],
              ["Stationery", 100]
             ]
```

I want to merge this 2 array with unique value as follows,

```
            [
              ["Tech & Digital", 124],
              ["Stationery", 100],
              ["Gift Item", 125]
             ]
```

I tried `concat` function, but it's not working as expected.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1584370/how-to-merge-two-arrays-in-javascript

Comment: Since there is no 'built in' way to remove duplicate. you have to implement it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you know, I am sure others can make something a bit more eloquent but here is my stab at it using jquery.

```
var array1 = [
              ["Tech & Digital", 124],
              ["Stationery", 100]
             ]
var array2 = [
              ["Gift Item", 125],
              ["Stationery", 100]
             ]
var obj = {}
jQuery.map(array1.concat(array2),function(i,v){return obj[i[0]] = i[1] })
array1 = jQuery.map(obj, function(j,w){
       return [].concat([[w,j]]);
    })
```

this is the same, but modified for a non-library solution. pre ECMAScript5.

```
var arr = array1.concat(array2), obj = {};
for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
    obj[arr[i][0]] = arr[i][1];
}
array1 = function() {
      var arr = [];
      for(key in obj){
       arr.push([[key,obj[key]]])
      }
      return arr;
}()
```

both return:

```
[["Tech & Digital", 124], ["Stationery", 100], ["Gift Item", 125]]
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you using nested arrays to emulate an object that preserves order? If so, then write a container object that handles the sorting for you.

If not, you can use Underscore or Lo-Dash:

```
_.uniq(_.union(array1, array2), false, JSON.stringify)
```

Since `[1] != [1]`, you have to compare them manually. `JSON.stringify` is one (hacky) way of doing it.

Comment: can't we do this without `Underscore` or `Lo-Dash`?